# Two nested for/loops without duplicated pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, permutation

We have array:

```
var arr = [0,1,2];
```

and loops:

```
for ( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var j=0; j<arr.length; j++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] == arr[j] ) continue;
        console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
```

and output:

```
0,1 //a--|
0,2 //b--|--|
1,0 //a--|  |
1,2 //c-----|--|
2,0 //b-----|  |
2,1 //c--------|
```

as we can see there are duplicated pairs (in comments a, b and c occurs twice)

the only way we can get rid of duplicated pairs is to store already "matched" pairs in some sort of memory?

```
var mem = {};

for ( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var j=0; j<arr.length; j++ ) {
        var left = i;
        var right = j;
        if ( left > right ) {
            var temp = right;
            right = left;
            left = temp;
        }

        if ( arr[i] == arr[j] || mem[arr[left]+","+arr[right]] ) continue;

        console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
        mem[arr[left]+","+arr[right]] = true;
    }
}
```

and output:

```
0,1
0,2
1,2
```

but this takes additional memory (for bigger arrays it takes a lot of it..)

is there any other way without storing anything additional?

Comment: short answer is ... No

Comment: Are these loops going to be millions large, because if not I don't see a reason to prematurely optimize. When this does cause measurable issues, there may be a filter that might be more efficient, I'm not an expert on them. Even then, I suspect it does the same memory usage, it's just less obvious in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your input array is unique why don't you just start your j from i+1

```
for ( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var j= i + 1 ; j<arr.length; j++ ) {
        console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is actually more efficient than the way I did it, although it used the same principle. Nice!

Comment: @Feathercrown: and also better fits for linked-list.

Comment: Also, while its the same big O as yours, it'll run faster in practice because of shorter for loop.

Answer (score 1):

One possible algorithm is as follows:

1. Sort the array.
2. Remove duplicate values (leave 1 behind) from the array, for every value `x` that has a duplicate, output `(x,x)`.
3. For every pair of indices `i` and `j` such that `i < j`, output the corresponding pair `(i,j)`.

This might not produce sorted output though, but it does deal with duplicate values and an unsorted input array.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var j=0; j<arr.length; j++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] == arr[j] || j<i) continue;
        console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Explanation:
If j is less than i, then you can switch i and j to get another output with the same two values. But if you keep j "ahead" of i in the array, then no duplicates will be outputted.

How it "looks":

o=array value

x=arr[i]

|=arr[j]

-=arr[i] and arr[j] are both at this spot

-oooo //Continue

x|ooo

xo|oo

xoo|o
xooo|

Then, without the change:

|xooo //Outputted! Same as line(/step) 2!

o-ooo //Continue

ox|oo

With the change:
|xooo //j is before i, so do not output. Avoids duplication of line(/step) 2.

o-ooo //Continue

ox|oo

etc.

Comment: like Amin J answer, with extra unnecessary computations.

Comment: @TomerW Yeah, I saw that. I'm still leaving it, though.